# Potsgres SQL query for min and max timeseries data with Timezones

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone

Hoping some gurus can help my brain sort out a query that involves timezones and grouping.

Context: We have a water meter that is based in Adelaide/Australia (for instance) and it is +10 hours from UTC. 
All my data is stored at UTC in the DB.
I have a date picker for the consumption of water between 2 dates on the UI. 
This takes the timezone that has been allocated to the meter in the DB and calculates the UTC date range to send to the API for the Postgres Query.

But I am having a problem trying to get the results (efficiently) in one or many queries.

Below is what I have so far,  but it is grouping by day and doesn't take the time into consideration, therefore pointless for my exercise.

Does anyone have any suggestions for the best way to do an efficient SQL Query for this?

```
SELECT
    "Meters"."Id" AS meterId,
    "Meters"."Name" AS meterName,
    "Meters"."DeviceId" AS meterSerial,
    "Meters"."SiteId",
    "Meters"."Bulk",
    "MeterTypes"."Settings",
    "MeterTypes"."MeterType" AS TYPE,
    "Meters"."MeterType",
    "minMaxQuery"."RMin",
    "minMaxQuery"."RMax",
    ( "minMaxQuery"."RMax" - "minMaxQuery"."RMin" ) AS consumption,
    "minMaxQuery"."RDate" 
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        "Readings"."MeterId",
        MIN ( "Readings"."Value" ) AS "RMin",
        MAX ( "Readings"."Value" ) AS "RMax",
        DATE ( "Readings"."Timestamp" ) AS "RDate" 
    FROM
        "Readings"
        LEFT JOIN "Meters" ON "Readings"."MeterId" = "Meters"."Id" 
    WHERE
        "Meters"."SiteId" = $1 
        AND "Timestamp" BETWEEN $2 
        AND $3 
    GROUP BY
        DATE ( "Readings"."Timestamp" ),
        "Readings"."MeterId" 
    ORDER BY
        DATE ( "Readings"."Timestamp" ),
        "Readings"."MeterId" 
    ) AS "minMaxQuery"
    LEFT JOIN "Meters" ON "minMaxQuery"."MeterId" = "Meters"."Id"
    LEFT JOIN "MeterTypes" ON "Meters"."MeterType" = "MeterTypes"."Id" 
WHERE
    (
        "MeterTypes"."MeterType" :: TEXT LIKE'Cold' 
        OR "MeterTypes"."MeterType" :: TEXT LIKE'Hot' 
        OR "MeterTypes"."MeterType" :: TEXT LIKE'Electricity' 
        OR "MeterTypes"."MeterType" :: TEXT LIKE'Gas' 
        OR "MeterTypes"."MeterType" :: TEXT LIKE'Thermal' 
    ) 
ORDER BY
    "MeterTypes"."MeterType",
    "minMaxQuery"."RDate",
    "Bulk",
    "minMaxQuery"."MeterId";
```

Comment: Is your timestamp field a `timestamp` or a `timestamptz`?  Is your session time zone set the same as the meters? Or potentially different?  Do you store the meter's time zone name somewhere?

Comment: Also, are you just asking how to group by local date of a specific time zone? Or something else?  Have you considered just storing that local date in a separate field to begin with?